# system start command not working in XP

Tags: windows, perl, windows-xp, spawn

I'm trying to run a script that calls child processes on Windows XP. It was originally designed in Windows 7. Everything seems to work save the spawn:

I run a command

```
system "start", "cmd.exe", "/k","C:/path/perl.exe","C:/users/script.pl";
```

in Windows 7, and it spawns `script.pl` into a new console.

The same command in XP tells me that it can't find `start`.

When I run

```
system "cmd.exe", "/k","C:/path/perl.exe","C:/users/script.pl";
```

It doesn't open a new console.

How do I spawn a new process in a new console in XP?

Comment: Take at look at [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Win32%3A%3AProcess&mode=all)

Comment: I tried with Win32::Process and Win32::Job. Both work in Windows 7, but neither work in XP. There is no new console, and when I check task manager, nothing even starts from XP.

Comment: Does `start` call an executable `start.exe` that I could just download into my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember a thing about XP, but on W7 `start` is provided by `cmd.exe` and isn't a separate executable. So I'm surprised to see it first in the list of parameters.

I think the original author screwed it up badly so that `cmd.exe` is run implicitly to do the `start`, which then runs a second copy of `cmd.exe` which runs perl.

In the end, I assume you want to run the Perl program and wait until it completes, so you need

```
system qw{ cmd.exe /K C:/path/perl.exe C:/users/script.pl }
```

I also think the `/K` should be `/C`, as the former asks for another prompt from the shell once the command exits, whereas the latter just runs the command and stops.

Check your mileage.

Oh, and you can't use `qw` as I have if there are spaces in the paths.